# The vertical scroll bar is moved to end list when inside the horizontal scroll bar

Tags: react-native, react-native-web

Im using two scrollview to design table and skip first row as header when scroll down. But scroll bar is pushed to end View. Help me.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rcsox.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/73z7H.png)

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true} contentContainerStyle={GeneralStyle.ViewTable} >
<View style={[GeneralStyle.ViewMidContentTableTopSc, { height: 40, paddingRight: apaddingRight }]}>
<View style={GeneralStyle.ViewMidContentHeaderRow}>
    <View style={AccessData.CheckSecurityMenu("", userRole) === true ? (GeneralStyle.viewColW100) : (GeneralStyle.viewColHide)}>
        ..
    </View>
    <View style={AccessData.CheckSecurityMenu("", userRole) === true ? (GeneralStyle.viewColW100) : (GeneralStyle.viewColHide)}>
        ..
    </View><View style={AccessData.CheckSecurityMenu("", userRole) === true ? (GeneralStyle.viewColW100) : (GeneralStyle.viewColHide)}>
        ..
    </View><View style={AccessData.CheckSecurityMenu("", userRole) === true ? (GeneralStyle.viewColW100) : (GeneralStyle.viewColHide)}>
        ..
    </View><View style={AccessData.CheckSecurityMenu("", userRole) === true ? (GeneralStyle.viewColW100) : (GeneralStyle.viewColHide)}>
        ..
    </View><View style={AccessData.CheckSecurityMenu("", userRole) === true ? (GeneralStyle.viewColW100) : (GeneralStyle.viewColHide)}>
        ..
    </View><View style={AccessData.CheckSecurityMenu("", userRole) === true ? (GeneralStyle.viewColW100) : (GeneralStyle.viewColHide)}>
        ..
    </View><View style={AccessData.CheckSecurityMenu("", userRole) === true ? (GeneralStyle.viewColW100) : (GeneralStyle.viewColHide)}>
        ..
    </View><View style={AccessData.CheckSecurityMenu("", userRole) === true ? (GeneralStyle.viewColW100) : (GeneralStyle.viewColHide)}>
        ..
    </View>
</View>
</View>
<View style={[GeneralStyle.ViewMidContentTableMidSc, {}]} >
<ScrollView>
    <View style={[GeneralStyle.ViewRowContentTable, { height: windowHeight - 190 }]}>
        {listDefFilter.map((item) => {
            //var i = 1;
            return (
                <View style={GeneralStyle.ViewMidContentTableRow} key={item.RowID}>
                    <View style={[GeneralStyle.ViewMidContentTableRow, { borderWidth: 0 }]} key={item.RowID}>
                        <View style={...}>
                            
                            </View>
                        <View style={...}>
                            
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    
                </View>
            );
            //i += 1;
        })}
        <View style={[GeneralStyle.ViewMidContentTableRowEmp, { height: 35 }]}></View>
    </View>
</ScrollView>
</View>
                                </ScrollView>
```

The vertical scroll bar is moved to end list when inside the horizontal scroll bar